# Prove $x(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n\rightarrow 0$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $x\in[0,1]$, and define $f=x(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Certainly $x(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. How to prove that this convergence is uniform by it is bounded by $\frac{2}{n+1}$?

Comment: Hint: what is the maximum and of your function over $[0,1]$?

Comment: The maximum will involve the term $x$.

Comment: It won't if you fix $n$.

Comment: $f'=(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n+xn(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^{n-1}(-\frac{1}{2})$, and set them equal to $0$. Did I do the first derivative wrong?

Comment: Use the binomial theorem.

Comment: I think it's fine. Equate it to zero now.

Comment: @Wojowu yeah, that's where I got stuck with the algebra...

Comment: @Wojowu so then $2(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n=xn(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^{n-1}$, now it seems pretty hard to write $x$ in terms of $n$...

Comment: You can divide both sides by $(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^{n-1}$...

Comment: @Wojowu Right!!... yikes... I couldn't figure this out...

Comment: @Wojowu So I end up with $nx=2-x$. Did I do it wrong? It seems like I have hard time of writing $x$ interns of $n$ again...

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n=x(1-\frac12 x)^n$

The following are true:

- $[0,1]$ is compact,
- $f_n(x) \ge f_{n+1}(x)$ (check this)
- Each $f_n$ is continuous, and $f_n(x) \to 0$ for all $x$ (note that $0$ is continuous)

Therefore you may apply [Dini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem) to conclude the convergence is uniform.

Comment: But what did you do with the term $x$?

Comment: I forgot about it, is what I did. I'll edit my comment -- the answer is now correct.

Comment: Thank you, but without using Dini's theorem, how to prove this is bounded by a term that only involves $n$?