# How to prove that this convergence is uniform by it is bounded by $\frac{2}{n+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $x\in[0,1]$, and define $f=x(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Certainly $x(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. How to prove that this convergence is uniform by it is bounded by $\frac{2}{n+1}$?

Attempt: The limit function is $0$, I tried to consider the maximum by using the first derivative. After that I have $nx=2-x$, which I'm having trouble to write $x$ in terms of $n$.
[Prove $x(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n\rightarrow 0$ uniformly](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452983/prove-x1-frac12xn-rightarrow-0-uniformly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to finding the maximum, use the following estimate.

With $0 < x \leqslant 1$ we have $0 < (1 - x/2) < 1$. There exists $a > 0$ such that $(1 - x/2) = 1/(1 +a)$. In this case  $a = x /(2-x)$ and, using Bernoulli's inequality $(1 +a)^n > na$, we have

$$x\left(1 - \frac{x}{2} \right)^n = \frac{x}{(1 + a)^n} < \frac{x}{na} .$$

From here you should be able to finish and show that $2/n$ is an upper bound.

Comment: I'm still confused... Where did this $a=x/(2-x)$ come from? Assume $a$ is defined that way, is $(1-\frac{x}{2})^n=\frac{1}{(1+a)^n}$? how?

Comment: @2ndaccount: Clarified above.  Handle the case $x=0$ and try to finish as suggested.

Comment: $(1 - x/2) = 1/(1+a) \implies a = x/(2-x)$. We want to write in terms of $1/(1+a)^n$ to apply Bernoulli and get an estimate in terms of $1/n$.

Comment: thank you. Is it true that using first derivative to find the maximum doesn't work?

Comment: Why would it not work?  Did you try to find it?   I just showed you how to find a uniform upper bound without specifically looking for the maximum.  It is located at $x_{\text{max}} = 2/(n+1)$ and it would have to be the case that $f(x_{\text{max}}) \leqslant 2/n$.

Comment: Yes. Taking the first derivative of $f$, we have $(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n-\frac{1}{2}xn(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^{n-1}$. By setting it equal to $0$, we have $(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^n=\frac{1}{2}xn(1-\frac{1}{2}x)^{n-1}$ so $1-\frac{1}{2}x=\frac{1}{2}xn$, i.e. $2-x=xn$. This is where I got stuck for separating $x$ and $n$, where I'm trying to write $x$ in terms of $n$...

Comment: So $2-x = xn \implies 2 = (n+1)x  \implies x = 2/(n+1)$. Then the maximum is $f(2/(n+1)) = \frac{2}{n+1}\left(1 - \frac{2}{2(n+1)} \right)^n< \frac{2}{n+1}$.  Done.  Or using the estimated bound of $2/n$ we reach the same conclusion of uniform convergence.